# How can we put scrollview in EditText field in android?

Tags: android, android-edittext, scrollview

There is Terms&Conditions screen in My application. I am putting Terms&conditions information in `EditText` field.

**My Requirment:**

I want to put `ScrollView` inside `EditText` to read terms and conditions text (since text is modr i need `ScrollView` in `EditText` field). How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should't use `EditText` for reading purposes. Use `TextView` inside `ScrollView`:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">   

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions" />

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply display your conditions and terms in a TextView, and to use scrolling ,you can just put your TextView in a ScrollView like this :

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollTerms" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_heigth="match_parent"
>
<TextView android:id="@+id/txtTerms" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_heigth="wrap_content"
       android:text="put your terms and conditions here ..."
>
</ScrollView>
```